# Integral for $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

In gamma function How do you evaluatate

$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{v^{z-1}}{v+1} dv$

which method could be fit to solve the integral?

The result should be

$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{v^{z-1}}{v+1} =\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the integral is a product of Gammas, or how to prove that product is $\pi\csc\pi z$?

Comment: Use contour integration! :P

Comment: You may just use the Euler/Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(1\pm z)$ and the Weierstrass product for $\frac{\sin z}{z}$. What is your *definition* of $\Gamma(z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, the substitution $v=\tan^2 t$ converts the integral to $$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2z-1}t\cos^{1-2z}t\,dt=\operatorname{B}(z,\,1-z)=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z).$$(Everything you need to know about Beta and Gamma functions to follow that is found [here](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/5/txe3da5h.htm).) On the other hand, the reflection formula is proven [as thus](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula#Proof). I'll make this answer more self-contained later, when it's clear which question the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx$$

$$\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-|x|}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(xz)}{z^2+1}dz$$ 
The second integral can be calculated through the use of complex residues.

$$\Gamma(s)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(xz)}{z^2+1}dzdx$$

By Fubini's Theorem: $$\Gamma(s)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{z^2+1}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cos(zx)dxdz$$

The inner integral is the Mellin Transform of $\Re(e^{-izx})$ which is equal to $\Gamma(s)\Re(iz)^{-s}=\Gamma(s)\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})z^{-s}$

So $$\Gamma(s)=\frac{2}{\pi}\Gamma(s)\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{-s}}{z^2+1}dz$$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{-s}}{z^2+1}dz=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec(\frac{\pi s}{2})$$
Let $u=z^2$ $dz=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{\frac{-s-1}{2}}}{u+1}du=\frac{\pi}{2}\sec(\frac{\pi s}{2})$$

Letting $s\to (1-2s)$ we arrive at the answer

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{s-1}}{u+1}du=\pi\csc(\pi s)$$

To achieve the integral in the form of the $\Gamma(s)$ function, all that is required is either Euler's Reflection Formula, or a substitution and the definition of the Beta function as explained in @J.G.'s answer.